# How do you use the Scanner class in java to store two words or more in a String variable, then the next input in another String variable?

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter title of the book: ");
    String title = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the author: ");
    String author = sc.next();

    String bookID = bookID();

    Book b = new Book(author,title,bookID,true);
    books.add(b);


    System.out.println( title + " by "+ author +" added to library.");
    System.out.println("Book ID: " + bookID);
```

This produces the following output with the title being "Gone with the Wind" and the author Margaret Mitchell:

```
Gone by with added to library
Book ID:456423156
```

Is there a way I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead of `Scanner#next()`. The latter only reads up to the next token delimiter which is a [whitespace character of some sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) by default.